# How to create right angle marks for 3D objects?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent,pst-eucl} 
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(8,6)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,-90,90}](-3,0){A}(3,0){C}(-1,-1){B}(0,5){S}
\pstTranslation[PosAngle=45]{B}{A}{C}[D]
\pstCircleABC[linestyle=none]{S}{A}{C}{I}
\pstInterLL[PosAngle=-60]{A}{C}{B}{D}{H}
\psline(S)(A)(B)(S)(C)(B)

\pstRightAngle{D}{H}{I}
\pstRightAngle{B}{H}{I}

\psset{linestyle=dashed}
\psline(B)(D)(A)(C)(D)(S)
\ncline{H}{I} \naput{$x$}
\ncline{A}{I} \naput{$R$}
\psset{SegmentSymbol=pstslash}
\pstSegmentMark{S}{I}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{I}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `pst-solides3d` package defines a `rightangle` object.

Comment: @Bernard I have just read pst-solides3d but I can't use it for my problem. what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-2)(4,6)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,-90,90}](-3,0){A}(3,0){C}(-1,-1){B}(0,5){S}
\pstTranslation[PosAngle=45]{B}{A}{C}[D]
\pstCircleABC[linestyle=none]{S}{A}{C}{I}
\pstInterLL[PosAngle=-60]{A}{C}{B}{D}{H}
\psline(S)(A)(B)(S)(C)(B)

\bgroup
    \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
    \pstGeonode([nodesep=10pt]{I}H){t}([nodesep=10pt]{B}H){l}([nodesep=-10pt]{B}H){r}
    \pstTranslation{H}{l}{t}[a1]
    \pstTranslation{H}{r}{t}[a2]
    \psline(l)(a1)(t)(a2)(r)
\egroup

\psset{linestyle=dashed}
\psline(B)(D)(A)(C)(D)(S)
\ncline{H}{I} \naput{$x$}
\ncline{A}{I} \naput{$R$}
\psset{SegmentSymbol=pstslash}
\pstSegmentMark{S}{I}
\pstSegmentMark{A}{I}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Secret Recipes

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]