# How to fill a right-angle mark with a color?

Tags: color, pstricks, fill, pst-eucl

I fails to fill the right-angle mark with green color as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.6,-1)(4.85,4)
\def\b{3}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,135,-45}](0,0){A}(0,\b){B}(\pscalculate{\b*sqrt(2)},0){D}
\pstTranslation[PosAngle=45]{A}{D}{B}[C]
\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{A}{C}{M}{D}{E}
\pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{M}{E}{C}
\psline(A)(B)(C)(D)(A)(C)(M)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to fill a right-angle mark with a color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If node A is not the origin, then use the coordinate pair `{AD,CD}` which is `{(4,3)}` instead of `{(C)}` for the rotation of `\rput`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.6,-1)(4.85,4)
    \def\b{3}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,135,-45}](0,0){A}(0,\b){B}(\pscalculate{\b*sqrt(2)},0){D}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=45]{A}{D}{B}[C]
    \pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
    \pstInterLL[PointName=none]{A}{C}{M}{D}{E}
    \rput{(C)}(E){\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0.2,0.2)}%%%%%
    \psline(A)(B)(C)(D)(A)(C)(M)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pst-eucl.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/ you can use:

```
\pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{M}{E}{C}
```

Comment: Please tell me know why the command \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{M}{E}{C} does not get the same result as \rput{(C)}(E){\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0.2,0.2)} by default.

Comment: it's not supported. That's all...  Maybe I'll change it or maybe not ..

Comment: " added fillstyle for angles " from up-to-date of pst-eucl.tex .... But the command \pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!50]{B}{C}{A}{$\theta$} does not work ...

Comment: And I replaced it by the command \psGetAngleABC[WedgeOpacity=1.2,WedgeColor=yellow,LabelSep=0.5](B)(C)(A){$\beta$}. How do you think ?

Comment: works only for RightAngle. Maybe later also for MarkAngle

Comment: Yes, :-) ; :-).

Comment: I uploaded a new `pst-euxl.tex`. Try again

Comment: " added fillstyle for angles " works fine! Thanks.

Comment: I need more tests until it will be uploaded officially to CTAN

Comment: Can you see it? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467387/how-to-create-right-angle-marks-for-3d-objects . And how do you think about it? :-). You don't answer it, so I can't ask any question!

Comment: 3D angles will not be supported by pst-eucl. You have to write your own macro.  Or use `pst-3dplot`

Comment: Oh, I see ah! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\def\b{3 }
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.6,-1)(4.85,4)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,135,-45,45}](0,0){A}(!0 \b){B}(!\b 2 sqrt mul 0){D}(D|B){C}
\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{A}{C}{M}{D}{E}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green](E)([nodesep=6pt]{C}E)([offset=6pt,nodesep=6pt]{C}E)([offset=6pt]{C}E)
\psline(A)(B)(C)(D)(A)(C)(M)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (Off topic) Where is the syntax ...(D|B){C}? I can't find it in pst-eucl.

Comment: @chishimotoji: it is a secret recipe in PSTricks. It can be used everywhere, `(A|B) `stands for `(A.x|B.y)`.

Comment: No, I want \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=.2,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]{M}{E}{C} to get a result like your syntax.( default )

Comment: @chishimotoji: You must change the library.

Answer (score 2):

With [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot), based on TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\b{3}
\tzcoors*(0,0)(A){$A$}[-135](0,\b)(B){$B$}[135]({\b*sqrt(2)},0)(D){$D$}[-45];
\tzcoor*($(B)-(A)+(D)-(A)$)(C){$C$}[45]
\tzcoor*($(B)!.5!(C)$)(M){$M$}
\tzpolygon(A)(B)(C)(D);
\tzline"AC"(A)(C)
\tzline"DM"(D)(M)
\tzXpoint*{AC}{DM}(E)
% angle marks
\tzrightanglemark*[draw,fill=green](M)(E)(C)
\tzanglemark*[draw,fill=red](A)(C)(D)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Herbert's solution can be generalized by replacing his

```
\rput{(C)}(E){\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0.2,0.2)}%%%%%
```

with

```
\pnode(C){c}% temporary 
\pnode(E){e}% temporary
\rput{!N-c.y N-e.y sub N-c.x N-e.x sub atan}(E){\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0.2,0.2)}%%%%%
```

Red alert: the temporary nodes are important and needed because it is one of PSTricks' hidden features. We cannot substitute `!N-C.y N-E.y sub N-C.x N-E.x sub atan` for `!N-c.y N-e.y sub N-c.x N-e.x sub atan`.

The complete code is as follows. I translated all points with `(1,1)` vector just to see a non-trivial effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](6,5)
    \def\b{3}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,135,-45}](1,1){A}(1,\pscalculate{\b+1}){B}(\pscalculate{\b*sqrt(2)+1},1){D}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=45]{A}{D}{B}[C]
    \pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{M}
    \pstInterLL[PointName=none]{A}{C}{M}{D}{E}
    \pnode(C){c}% temporary 
    \pnode(E){e}% temporary
    \rput{!N-c.y N-e.y sub N-c.x N-e.x sub atan}(E){\psframe[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](0.2,0.2)}%%%%%
    \psline(A)(B)(C)(D)(A)(C)(M)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hehe, thank you. :-))